# Laravel Nova create same record multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-nova

I am stuck with a issue on Laravel. I like to insert a records multiple times.
The user can add a amount, lets say 3. Than the insert query has to run 3 times.

I was able to make a observer but when i loop through there, it will still add one.

See the code below:

```
public function creating(CardOrder $cardOrder)
{
    if($amount = $cardOrder->amount) {
        unset($cardOrder->amount);
        for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i ++) {
            $cardOrder->entity_id = 1234;
            $cardOrder->group_id = 'test';
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that, and do i need a observer to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added them  `$cardOrder =  new CardOrder;`

```
  public function creating(CardOrder $cardOrder)
  {
    if($amount = $cardOrder->amount) {
        unset($cardOrder->amount);
         $cardOrder =  new CardOrder;
        for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i ++) {
            $cardOrder->entity_id = 1234;
            $cardOrder->group_id = 'test';
            $cardOrder->save();
        }
    }
}
```